# How to retain navigation menu items between android screen rotations?

Tags: android

I have a menu attached to a "navigationview" that has some static items arranged by group and I also have to populate some more items dynamically to it appending to the group ( called "group_users"). I am able to add menu items to a navigation view dynamically and view it under the navigationview of my DrawerLayout. However, when I rotate the screen, the dynamically added menu items disappear leaving behind on the static menu items. How do I retain the state of my menu after screen orientation changes? If it was OptionsMenu, I could use OnPrepareOptionsMenu() to check for the state of the menu. What should I do for Nav Draw Menu?

```
    if (!userName.isEmpty()) {
       navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).getSubMenu().add(R.id.menu_group_users, itemId,Menu.NONE, usrName);
    }
 else {
       navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).getSubMenu().add(R.id.menu_group_users, itemId, Menu.NONE, "unknown user");
    }
```

Here is my xml within DrawerLayout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:saveEnabled="true"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I once faced this issue and i basically just stored the values globally to make sure they were restored in screen rotation. When the screen rotates, the activity is created again, thats why you non static variables go empty

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I followed the same procedure to populate & clear menu items from a global var.